# Inserting Sudo password in Python

Tags: python, sudo

I am a newbie in Python. I have written a script for finding some files in Ubuntu which needs **sudo** access, the script has failed to show the desired output. Here is my script:

```
import subprocess

command_1 = "echo password".split()
command_2 = "sudo -S find / -iname 'vlc.png'".split()
file_open = open("find.log", "w")

comm_1 = subprocess.Popen(command_1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(command_2, stdin=comm_1.stdout, stdout=file_open)
```

The script works till the second last line, as it shows **password** in STDOUT. I am guessing the problem might be in the last line. I have tried some other solutions from SE but none of the solutions work for me except using **shell=True** which i am not willing to use.

I am aware that putting the password in plain text is a very very bad idea but as i am learning i just need to know why my code is not working.

EDIT:

```
import subprocess

command_1 = "echo password".split()
command_2 = "sudo -S find / -iname 'vlc.png'".split()
file_open = open("find.log", "w")

print subprocess.Popen(command_1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Output: **password**

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It doesn't output `password`, but `sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt` instead.

Comment: @Rawing: Please check my edits. The standard output of the second last command is the password.

Comment: If you use `shell=False` you should not have quotes around `vlc.png`. My suspicion is that this is your real problem, and that the whole `sudo` business is a red herring.

Comment: @tripleee: Removing quotes around **vlc.png** is not helping either.

Comment: Your second block of code, after the "EDIT:", never uses `command_2` in any way, and is therefore not going to make any attempt to run `sudo` or `find`. You shouldn't be surprised that it won't work as expected. Please carefully copy in the exact code that isn't working.

Comment: On StackOverflow, it is usually better to post a new question, instead of editing an old question, when you wish to make major changes to your question. This way, we don't confuse readers who see old answers to the original version of the question

Answer (score 1):

i recommend the use of [`sh`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) package for python

```
from sh import sudo

file = sudo.find("/", "-iname", "vlc.png")
```

Comment: From the github link: **If you use sudo, the user executing the script must have the NOPASSWD option set for whatever command that user is running, otherwise sudo will hang.** its the same thing that @Aaron mentioned and also needless to import an extra module by any means.

Comment: @heemayl indeed, but at least it will help you interact with your system in a much more easier and readable way

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler just to configure `sudo` such that a password is not needed. I assume your username is `user1` and you wish that `user1` may run `sudo find / -name vlc.png` without a password.

(Is this just to run on one machine, or do you wish others to be able to easily run it on their machine? If the latter, then I guess my answer doesn't help. Sorry!)

To do this run `sudo visudo`, which will safely edit the relevant config file, and insert this as the *last* line of the file:

```
user1    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: sudo find / -name vlc.png
```

This is a fairly typical problem - you could just search the internet for "sudo without passord" and you will find other webpages discussing this same solution.

(Note that I have removed the `-S` flag)

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I am aware of this sudo access without password and yeah its a way better solution. Although i am curious is there any way this can be done the way i have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the very last bit of your last line:

```
import subprocess

command_1 = "echo password".split()
command_2 = "sudo -S find / -iname 'vlc.png'".split()
file_open = open("find.log", "w")

comm_1 = subprocess.Popen(command_1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(command_2, stdin=comm_1.stdout, stdout=comm_1.stdout)
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                 This is the problem
```

You should not have `stdout=comm_1.stdout` there. I deleted it and it worked for me, printing the `find` output to the terminal.

Perhaps you intended to do `stdout = file_open` instead?

Comment: Exactly, thats what i intended to do and doing this is not solving the problem. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: could you please remove this answer, this may give wrong interpretation to the problem. i have fixed the typo.